# появился отступ снизу сайта

Tags: css, html5

у меня на сайте появилась белая полоса снизу, не могу понять из-за чего, убирал методом тыка разные блоки сайта - не помогло, но на другой страничке этого же сайта у меня нет полоски снизу. Моя первая большая верстка сайта, прошу слишком агрессивно не реагировать на ошибки, но если найдете, то укажите на них, пожалуйста, буду очень Вам благодарен =)

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

html {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Play, sans-serif;
}

.fullbg {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(img/fbg.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}


/*ШАПКА*/

#header {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-flex {
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-right .button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .38);
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.header-right .button {
  background-color: #000;
}

.button {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 12px 19px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.38px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.cart-img {
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* НАВИГАЦИЯ */

nav {
  width: 175px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.topnav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.topnav:hover a {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: .2;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.menu-link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 23px 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 718px) {
  .hamburger-menu {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
  }
  .header-right {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-left {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* добавляем "гамбургер" */

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #616161;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}


/* контейнер меню */

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}


/* элементы меню */

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}


/*БАННЕР*/

@media screen and (max-width: 715px) {
  .genban {
    display: none;
  }
}

.banner {
  height: 460px;
}

.banner-top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner-top p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.68px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 153px;
}

.banner-top span {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #111;
  margin-right: 204px;
  margin-top: 153px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.banner-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: space-around;
  /* margin-right: 205px;  */
  padding-top: 18px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.banner-container {
  width: 85%;
}

.banner-bottom p {
  position: relative;
  left: 71.7%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.pink {
  color: #fcac45;
}


/* некое отступление */

.job {
  /* height: 100%;
     background: #ffffff; */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(#fff, #000);
  contain: strict;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  background: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.job p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 2.6px;
}


/*  ФУТЕР */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .footer-right__bottom {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer-wrp {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .footer-left__bottom {
    position: relative;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: 10px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
  }
  .footer-contacts-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 130px;
    padding-left: 130px;
  }
  .footer-contacts-item .cont-p {
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .footer-pay {
    position: relative;
    right: 370px;
  }
  .footer-contacts-item p {
    position: relative;
    right: 15px;
  }
  .footer-pay-item img {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .footer-pay-item .visa {
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
  }
  .footer-pay-item .master {
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    bottom: 60px;
  }
  .footer-pay-item p {
    position: relative;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    left: 147px;
    padding-bottom: 27px;
  }
  .footer-menu {
    position: relative;
    left: 295px;
  }
  .footer-socials {
    display: none;
  }
}

.footer-pay-item p {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  padding: 44px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.footer-wrp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-menu {
  position: absolute;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0!important;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
  color: #767676;
}

.footer-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -15px;
  color: #767676;
}

.footer-menu ul li {
  padding: 5px;
}

.footer-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-menu ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fcac45;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.footer-left__center {
  margin: 60px 0 21px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.footer-socials {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1580px) {
  #footer {
    position: relative;
  }
}

.footer-socials .vk {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.footer-left__bottom p {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.footer-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.footer-right__bottom p {
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-socials a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-contacts-item p:first-child {
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: .78px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.footer-contacts-item p:nth-child(2) {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.footer-pay img:nth-child {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  position: relative;
  left: 8px;
}

.footer-pay img:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-pay {
  float: right;
  width: 166px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  text-align: right;
}

.footer-pay .visa {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer-right__bottom p {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 23px;
  letter-spacing: .72px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Рукодельница</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fullbg">
    <header id="header" class="header-main">
      <div class="container header-flex">
        <div class="header-left">
          <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img class="logo-img" src="img/logo.png" width="200" height="40" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
          <a href="product.html"><img class="cart-img" src="img/cart.png" width="25" height="25" alt="cart"></a>
          <a href="login.html" class="button">Мой аккаунт</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <nav>
        <div class="topnav responsive" id="myTopnav">
          <a href="picture.html">Lorem ipsum</a>
          <a href="rabbits.html">Lorem ipsum</a>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="hamburger-menu">
        <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
        <span></span>
      </label>
        <ul class="menu__box">
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="index.html">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="picture.html">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="rabbits.html">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="login.html">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="booking.html">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </header>


    <div class="banner">
      <div class="genban">
        <div class="banner-top">
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span>!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-center banner-container">
          <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="img/k1.jpg" width="300" height="180" alt="picture"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-bottom">
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="job">
    <p>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="footer-wrp">
      <div class="footer-left">
        <nav class="footer-menu">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="footer-left__center">
          <div class="footer-logo">
            <a href="/" class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active">
              <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" width="100" height="30" alt="logo">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-socials">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <img class="vk" src="img/vk-icon.png" width="20" height="20" alt="vk">
            </a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <img class="inst" src="img/insta-icon.png" width="20" height="20" alt="insta">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-left__bottom">
          <p>© 2019, Lorem ipsum</p>
          <!-- <a href="/storage/public_offer.pdf" target="_blank">Публичная оферта</a> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-right">
        <div class="footer-right-top">
          <div class="footer-contacts">
            <div class="footer-contacts-item">
              <p class="cont-p">E-mail:</p>
              <p class="cont-p1">Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="footer-pay">
            <div class="footer-pay-item">
              <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
              <img class="visa" src="img/visa-grey.png" alt="visa">
              <img class="master" src="img/master-grey.png" alt="master">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right__bottom">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum.<br> «Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum<br> Lorem ipsum
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: код верните.. И да, как вы можете заметить, в сниппете данная проблема не отображается. Скорее всего проблема возникает от сторонних плагинов/скриптов/стилей и т.п.

Comment: В сниппете данная проблема показывается, откройте полностью сайт, а не частично

Comment: я код никуда и не убирал

Comment: HamSter, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать дополнительно всему документу `body { overflow: hidden; }` или другой обертке разметки.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

html {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Play, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullbg {
 
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(img/fbg.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}


/*ШАПКА*/

#header {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-flex {
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-right .button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .38);
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.header-right .button {
  background-color: #000;
}

.button {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 12px 19px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.38px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.cart-img {
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* НАВИГАЦИЯ */

nav {
  width: 175px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.topnav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.topnav:hover a {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: .2;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.menu-link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 23px 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 718px) {
  .hamburger-menu {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
  }
  .header-right {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-left {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* добавляем "гамбургер" */

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #616161;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}


/* контейнер меню */

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}


/* элементы меню */

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
}


/*БАННЕР*/

@media screen and (max-width: 715px) {
  .genban {
    display: none;
  }
}

.banner {
  height: 460px;
}

.banner-top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner-top p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.68px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 153px;
}

.banner-top span {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #111;
  margin-right: 204px;
  margin-top: 153px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.banner-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: space-around;
  /* margin-right: 205px;  */
  padding-top: 18px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.banner-container {
  width: 85%;
}

.banner-bottom p {
  position: relative;
  left: 71.7%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.pink {
  color: #fcac45;
}


/* некое отступление */

.job {
  /* height: 100%;
     background: #ffffff; */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(#fff, #000);
  contain: strict;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  background: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.job p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 2.6px;
}


/*  ФУТЕР */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .footer-right__bottom {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer-wrp {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .footer-left__bottom {
    position: relative;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: 10px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
  }
  .footer-contacts-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 130px;
    padding-left: 130px;
  }
  .footer-contacts-item .cont-p {
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .footer-pay {
    position: relative;
    right: 370px;
  }
  .footer-contacts-item p {
    position: relative;
    right: 15px;
  }
  .footer-pay-item img {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .footer-pay-item .visa {
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
  }
  .footer-pay-item .master {
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    bottom: 60px;
  }
  .footer-pay-item p {
    position: relative;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    left: 147px;
    padding-bottom: 27px;
  }
  .footer-menu {
    position: relative;
    left: 295px;
  }
  .footer-socials {
    display: none;
  }
}

.footer-pay-item p {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  padding: 44px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.footer-wrp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-menu {
  position: absolute;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0!important;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
  color: #767676;
}

.footer-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -15px;
  color: #767676;
}

.footer-menu ul li {
  padding: 5px;
}

.footer-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-menu ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fcac45;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.footer-left__center {
  margin: 60px 0 21px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.footer-socials {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1580px) {
  #footer {
    position: relative;
  }
}

.footer-socials .vk {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.footer-left__bottom p {
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.footer-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.footer-right__bottom p {
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-socials a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-contacts-item p:first-child {
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: .78px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.footer-contacts-item p:nth-child(2) {
  color: #bfbfbf;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.footer-pay img:nth-child {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  position: relative;
  left: 8px;
}

.footer-pay img:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-pay {
  float: right;
  width: 166px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  text-align: right;
}

.footer-pay .visa {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer-right__bottom p {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 23px;
  letter-spacing: .72px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Рукодельница</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fullbg">
    <header id="header" class="header-main">
      <div class="container header-flex">
        <div class="header-left">
          <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img class="logo-img" src="img/logo.png" width="200" height="40" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
          <a href="product.html"><img class="cart-img" src="img/cart.png" width="25" height="25" alt="cart"></a>
          <a href="login.html" class="button">Мой аккаунт</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <nav>
        <div class="topnav responsive" id="myTopnav">
          <a href="picture.html">Lorem ipsum</a>
          <a href="rabbits.html">Lorem ipsum</a>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="hamburger-menu">
        <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
        <span></span>
      </label>
        <ul class="menu__box">
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="index.html">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="picture.html">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="rabbits.html">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="login.html">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="booking.html">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </header>


    <div class="banner">
      <div class="genban">
        <div class="banner-top">
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span>!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-center banner-container">
          <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="img/k1.jpg" width="300" height="180" alt="picture"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-bottom">
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="job">
    <p>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="footer-wrp">
      <div class="footer-left">
        <nav class="footer-menu">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="footer-left__center">
          <div class="footer-logo">
            <a href="/" class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active">
              <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" width="100" height="30" alt="logo">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-socials">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <img class="vk" src="img/vk-icon.png" width="20" height="20" alt="vk">
            </a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              <img class="inst" src="img/insta-icon.png" width="20" height="20" alt="insta">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-left__bottom">
          <p>© 2019, Lorem ipsum</p>
          <!-- <a href="/storage/public_offer.pdf" target="_blank">Публичная оферта</a> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-right">
        <div class="footer-right-top">
          <div class="footer-contacts">
            <div class="footer-contacts-item">
              <p class="cont-p">E-mail:</p>
              <p class="cont-p1">Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="footer-pay">
            <div class="footer-pay-item">
              <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
              <img class="visa" src="img/visa-grey.png" alt="visa">
              <img class="master" src="img/master-grey.png" alt="master">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right__bottom">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum.<br> «Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum<br> Lorem ipsum
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```